# In Excel, how to find a average from selected cells

Tags: excel

Need your help.
I have an excel sheet with two columns, like this:

[image: his:]

I would to find an average of the number in the cells from column 2 that correspond to the numbers in column 1 which end either in 2 or 5. If column 2 has a blank cell or a letter, it should be ignored.

Comment: sorry. the picture was an example. Instead of ending in 0, 7 or 8, the question would be ending in 5 or 2

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for that. Noob here :(

Answer (score 1):

If one has the dynamic array formula FILTER():

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(B2:B15,ISNUMBER(MATCH(--RIGHT(A2:A15),{2,5},0))))
```

[image]

If not then use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(--RIGHT(A2:A15),{2,5},0)),B2:B15))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Nice use of ISNUMBER/MATCH here.

Comment: Thank you, but when I use this last formula in Excel 2019, it gives the error: "There's a problem with this formula". When I close the error message, it highlights the first comma of the formula.:/

Comment: Then change all the `,` to `;` to be in line with your local settings.

Comment: Following your advice I used the formula:
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(--RIGHT(A2:A15);{2,5};0));B2:B15))

After pressing Ctrl-Shift-Enter the result is DIV/0.
Thank you for your effort!

Comment: you forgot the `,` in `{2,5}` make that `{2;5}`

Comment: please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.